# Most efficient way to retrieve daily data records grouped by month using EF 6

Tags: sql-server-2012, linq-to-entities, grouping, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have a table with the following structure:

```
| Column Name | Type           | 
|-------------|--------------- |
| ProjectId   | INT            |     
| StartDate   | INT            |   
| Amount      | DECIMAL(12, 2) |
```

The `StartDate` is an `INT`, but it actually represents a day, in the format `YYYYMMDD`.

The table stores daily numeric values for a project (only working days are stored, no Sunday or Saturday), as follows:

```
| ProjectId | StartDate | Amount |
|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 1         | 20140926  | 0.5    |
| 1         | 20140929  | 0.5    |
| 1         | 20140930  | 0.8    |
| 1         | 20141001  | 1      |     
| 1         | 20141002  | 1      |  
| 1         | 20141003  | 0.5    |
| 2         | 20141001  | 0.6    |
| 2         | 20141002  | 0.5    |
```

What would be the most efficient way to get the average monthly values for each project? I am using EF 6 (the `DbContext` approach) and SQL Server 2012? I am looking for a solution using Linq-to-Entities.

The ideal result would be something like this:

```
| ProjectId | StartDate | Amount |
|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 1         | 20140926  | 0.6    |
| 1         | 20141001  | 0.83   |
| 2         | 20141001  | 0.55   |
```

I have a solution, but I'm not sure it's optimal:

```
var results = dbContext.ProjectValues
                .GroupBy(pv =>
                    new
                    {
                        ProjectId = pv.ProjectId,
                        Year = pv.StartDate.Year,
                        Month = pv.StartDate.Month,
                    })
                .Select(g =>
                    new
                    {
                        ProjectId = g.Key.ProjectId,
                        StartDate = g.Min(v => v.StartDate),
                        Amount = g.Average(v => v.Amount)
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `GROUP BY` project id and month 
As date is stored as int, converting into date using cast

```
SELECT ProjectID, 
       AVG(Amount) as AverageAmount, 
       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(CAST(StartDate AS VARCHAR(12)) AS DATE)), 0)  
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ProjectID, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(CAST(StartDate AS VARCHAR(12)) AS DATE)), 0)
```

Comment: While the SQL code is correct, I would like a solution that uses linq-to-entities.

Comment: @kjv, got it. i am not expert in linq-to-entities.